# CSS | Flexbox | text

Tags: html, css

I am working on an assignment I have to make a playlist but the problem is that the sentences are too long and that causes the spacing between the playlist covers to be too long or odd, I want the sentences to be able to break under each other but it just doesn't want to work

could you help me, thanks in advance!

[My work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdI8Q.png)
[Result i need to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbvwd.png)

```
////////////////CSS////////////////////////
/*flexbox parent*/
.playlists{

display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
gap: 20px;



}


/*flexbox children // calbum overs*/
.covers{

width: 200px;
padding: 15px;

}

//////////////// HTML//////////////////////////////
<!--Main Pagina // Player-->  
<h1 class="titel"> Popular playlists right now</h1>


<section class= "playlists">

  <div class="cover">

    <img src="./Cove images/british-soul-invasion.jpg" alt="British soul invasion" style="height: 10rem;width:10rem">
    <h4>British soul invasion</h4>
    <p>Flo, Craig David, Lil Silva, Charlotte Day Wilson</p>

  </div>

  <div class="cover">
    <img src="./Cove images/chill-pop.jpg" alt=""style="height: 10rem;width:10rem">
    <h4>Chill pop</h4>
    <p>Hailee Steinfeld, Craig David, Galantis, Doja cat</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems like you just have a typo. Your CSS says `.covers`, but the class in the HTML is `cover`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/CSS/word-wrap) and [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap).